# Matrix equation and \notag

Tags: amsmath

My problem is related to the following "equation":

```
\begin{align}
\left(
\begin{matrix} 
    \shat{X} \notag \\ 
    \shat{X}' \notag \\ 
    \shat{Y} \notag \\ 
        \shat{Y}' \\
    \end{matrix} 
\right)_{n+1} 
= R(\omega_x, \omega_y) 
\left(
    \begin{matrix}
        \shat{X}  \\
        \shat{X}' + \shat{X}^2 - \chi \shat{Y}^2 + \kappa \left( \shat{X}^3 - 3 \chi \shat{X} \shat{Y}^2 \right)  \\
        \shat{Y}  \\
        \shat{Y}' - 2 \chi \shat{X} \shat{Y} - \kappa \left( \chi^2 \shat{Y}^3     - 3 \chi \shat{X}^2 \shat{Y} \right)  \\
    \end{matrix}
\right)_n 
\end{align}
```

It looks like I have to use `notag` for each line to avoid the individual line/equation numbering. Why is that ?

The next problem is: when I use 'notag' for each line, then the result is completely ugly, and the delimiters are in the wrong order (something strange with `)` before `(` ...

I'm using `memoir` with `amsmath`.

**EDIT:**

The `shat` command is defined as

```
\newcommand{\shat}[1]{\ensuremath{\hat{#1}}}
```

and it seems to work.

The problem looks the same for this simpler case:
[image]

Comment: Where does the `\shat` command comes from?

Comment: @Gonzalo : I edited the question.

Comment: Two side comments: (a) why not use `pmatrix` instead of `\left( \begin{matrix}...\end{matrix}\right)`? (b) there's no need to include the line break `\\\` after the last row of the matrix entries.

Comment: (after the update) I cannot reproduce. Wrapping your code inside `\documentclass{memoir} \usepackage{amsmath}`, with the definition of `\shat` in the preamble, and with the `\notag` removed, compiles just fine. Can you include a full minimum example (including preamble etc.)?

Comment: @Willie (a) Using `pmatrix` doesn't solve the problem, and I don't know how to produce the indices on the delimiters using `pmatrix`  (b) OK.

Comment: there is only one display line here. why bother to use `align`? if there is to be no equation number, `\[ ... \]` would work just fine, and no need to suppress equation numbers.

Comment: @Willie: I found the problem: incompatibility between `memoir` and `tabls`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot reprocude the problem, please post a full minimal example. This (using `pmatrix` works fine)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\shat}[1]{\ensuremath{\hat{#1}}}  
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} 
  \shat{X}  \\ 
  \shat{X}' \\ 
  \shat{Y}  \\ 
  \shat{Y}' \\
\end{pmatrix}_{n+1} 
= R(\omega_x, \omega_y) 
\begin{pmatrix}
  \shat{X}  \\
  \shat{X}' + \shat{X}^2 - \chi \shat{Y}^2 + \kappa \left( \shat{X}^3
    - 3 \chi \shat{X} \shat{Y}^2 \right)  \\ 
  \shat{Y}  \\
  \shat{Y}' - 2 \chi \shat{X} \shat{Y} - \kappa \left( \chi^2
     \shat{Y}^3     - 3 \chi \shat{X}^2 \shat{Y} \right)  \\ 
    \end{pmatrix}_n 
 \notag
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With your example I obtain what I want, if I remove the notag... and I was about to post an example of my code almost similar ... except for other packages I load. In my case every line of the matrices are numbered...

Comment: @Cedric: so one of the other packages is causing problems. Try commenting out all packages in your preamble and uncommenting them one by one, and see which one causes the error. If you can't find it, you should probably post your full example by editing the question text.

Comment: @Willie: thanks, apparently it was a problem with `tabls`.